# Placing the two most voted posts at the top (in a Wordpress site that uses the Vote it up plugin)?

Tags: plugins

I'm using the [Vote it up](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vote-it-up/) plugin.

Is there a way of placing the two most voted posts at the top? (Like in Youtube)?

I'm not very sure if this is hard or easy to accomplish.

**EDIT:**

Someone posted a method in the Wordpress forums [here](http://file:///home/alex/Desktop/plugin-vote-it-up-show-top-voted-post-in-index-page.html), but [Mike Schindel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/89/mikeschinkel) said:

> This example is absolutely AWFUL. It
>   may work but it's far more code than
>   you needs and may break on a future
>   version of WordPress.

I've been playing with Wordpress for a while but Im still a PHP beginner.

Is there a way of fixing that code posted in the Wordpress forums?
Or a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a while back i used that plugin and i needed a way to list most voted posts so after looking at the plugin's widget code and i came up with this function:

```
function top_voted($number){
    $a = SortVotes();
    echo '<div class="voted">';
    $rows = 0;
    //Now does not include deleted posts
    $i = 0;
    while ($rows < $number)) {
        if ($a[0][$i][0] != '') {
                $postdat = get_post($a[0][$i][0]);
            if (!empty($postdat)) {
                $rows++;
                echo '<div class="fore">';
                echo '<div class="votecount" style="width: 1em; color: #555555; font-weight: bold;">'.$a[1][$i][0].' </div><div><a href="'.$postdat->guid.'" title="'.$postdat->post_title.'">'.$postdat->post_title.'</a></div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
        if ($i < count($a[0])) {
            $i++;
        } else {
            break; //exit the loop
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Usage:

```
top_voted(5);
```

Comment: So the first part goes to `functions.php` and the usage part: `top_voted(5);` goes inside The Loop? or all that code (the first part and the usage part) goes in a template file?

Comment: i cant remeber but you can try to add the function to the functions.php and the top_voted(5); replaces the loop, so you dont need the loop at all.

Comment: Yeah I found that code in `votingfunctions.php`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be using postmeta to save votes. I would do that by doing a 
[query_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) order by that meta value and get two posts & save their ID in an array and then again use query_posts with `post__not_in` to not to include those posts in the remaining loop

Comment: it uses its own tables and not postmeta.

Comment: Alrite, then with your solution, he can save IDs and exclude them in the regular loop.